# Defining a function a -> String, which works for types without Show?

Tags: class, haskell

I'd like to define a function which can "show" values of any type, with special behavior for types which actually do define a `Show` instance:

```
magicShowCast :: ?

debugShow :: a -> String
debugShow x = case magicShowCast x of
    Just x' -> show x'
    Nothing -> "<unprintable>"
```

This would be used to add more detailed information to error messages when something goes wrong:

```
-- needs to work on non-Showable types
assertEq :: Eq a => a -> a -> IO ()
assertEq x y = when (x /= y)
    (throwIO (AssertionFailed (debugShow x) (debugShow y)))

data CanShow = CanShow1
             | CanShow 2
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data NoShow = NoShow1
            | NoShow2
    deriving (Eq)

-- AssertionFailed "CanShow1" "CanShow2"
assertEq CanShow1 CanShow2

-- AssertionFailed "<unprintable>" "<unprintable>"
assertEq NoShow1 NoShow2
```

Is there any way to do this? I tried using various combinations of GADTs, existential types, and template haskell, but either these aren't enough or I can't figure out how to apply them properly.

Comment: Closely related reading: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The real answer:** You can't. Haskell intentionally doesn't define a generic "serialize to string" function, and being able to do so without *some* type class constraint would violate parametricity all over town. Dreadful, just dreadful.

If you don't see why this poses a problem, consider the following type signature:

```
something :: (a, a) -> b -> a
```

How would you implement this function? The generic type means it has to be either `const . fst` or `const . snd`, right? Hmm.

```
something (x,y) z = if debugShow z == debugShow y then y else x
```

```
> something ('a', 'b') ()
'a'
> something ('a', 'b') 'b'
'b'
```

*Oooooooops!* So much for being able to reason about your program in any sane way. That's it, `show`'s over, go home, it was fun while it lasted.

---

**The terrible, no good, unwise answer:** Sure, if you don't mind *shamelessly cheating*. Did I mention that example above was an actual GHCi session? Ha, ha.

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import GHC.Vacuum

debugShow :: a -> String
debugShow = show . nameGraph . vacuumLazy

assertEq :: Eq a => a -> a -> IO ()
assertEq x y = when (x /= y) . throwIO . AssertionFailed $ 
    unlines ["assertEq failed:", '\t':debugShow x, "=/=", '\t':debugShow y]

data NoShow = NoShow1
            | NoShow2
    deriving (Eq)
```

```
> assertEq NoShow1 NoShow2
*** Exception: assertEq failed:
    [("|0",["NoShow1|1"]),("NoShow1|1",[])]
=/=
    [("|0",["NoShow2|1"]),("NoShow2|1",[])]
```

Oh. Ok. That looks like a *fantastic* idea, doesn't it.

Anyway, this doesn't quite give you what you want, since there's no obvious way to fall back to a proper `Show` instance when available. On the other hand, [this lets you do a lot more than `show` can do](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum-1.0.0), so perhaps it's a wash.

Seriously, though. Don't do this in actual, working code. Ok, error reporting, debugging, logging... that makes sense. But otherwise, it's probably very ill-advised.

Comment: Ooh, I'm always up for some shameless cheating! I don't see this as any worse than `unsafePerformIO`, from a semantic point of view, and it's nice to have a `stringDammit` function available.

Comment: @John Millikin: This *is* `unsafePerformIO`, of course, just like with `Debug.Trace.trace`. The real function is named `dump` and returns an `IO` action. `vacuum` & co. wrap this to provide a controlled amount of cheating for pure code, which should also let you do things like check whether something is an un-forced thunk.

Comment: Right, I looked at the source to "vacuum". I'm actually planning on using `dumpLazy`, since it's OK for `debugShow` to be of type `a -> IO String`.

Answer (score 3):

I asked this question a while ago on the haskell-cafe list, and the experts said no. Here are some good responses,

- http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/091744.html
- http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/091746.html

The second one mentions GHC advanced overlap, but my experience was that it doesn't really work.

For your particular problem, I'd introduce a typeclass

```
class MaybeShow a where mshow :: a -> String
```

make anything that is showable do the logical thing

```
instance Show a => MaybeShow a where mshow = show
```

and then, if you have a fixed number of types which wouldn't be showable, say

```
instance MaybeShow NotShowableA where mshow _ = "<unprintable>"
```

of course you could abstract it a little,

```
class NotShowable a
instance NotShowable a => MaybeShow a where mshow _ = "<unprintable>"
instance NotShowable NotShowableA -- etc.
```

Comment: Hm -- one of your links directs to http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap , which looks like it might have a workable solution using horrible type-system hackery (by Oleg, natch).

Comment: That's an interesting approach in the link, but I think it's ultimately useless.  It requires creating new instances for every type (or at least a giant HList).  If you're willing to do that, it's probably less work (and more correct/extensible) to create new show instances for every type which needs them.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be able to.  The simplest way to implement type classes is by having them compile into an extra parameter

```
 foo :: Show s => a -> s
```

turns into

```
 foo :: show -> a -> s
```

The program just passess around the type class instances (like v-tables in C++) as ordinary data.  This is why you can trivially use things that look not just like multiple dispatch in OO languages, but can dispatch off the return type.

The problem is that a signature

```
 foo :: a -> String
```

has no way of getting the implementation of `Show` that goes for `a` in cases when it has one.

You might be able to get something like this to work in particular implementations, with the correct language extensions (overlapping instance, etc) on, but I havent tried it

```
 class MyShow a where
   myShow :: a -> String

 instance (Show a) => MyShow a where
   myShow = show

 instance MyShow a where
   myShow = ...
```

one trick that might help is enable type families.  It can let you write code like

```
 instance (a' ~ a, Show a') => MyShow a
```

which can sometimes help you get code past the compiler that it doesn't think looks okay.

Comment: Doesn't work.  To the typechecker, `instance MyShow a` and `instance (Show a) => MyShow a` look exactly the same, because they both have `a` for the instance head.  You can force GHC to accept it with `IncoherentInstances`, but you can't use it in any sane way.